# Clear webview cache in broadcast receiver?

Tags: java, android, webview

I would like to clear the webview cache whenver a user updates my app. I have tried looking up at a lot of solutions but none seem to address this specifically.
I have registered the broadcast receiver as follows.

**Manifest file :**

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateReceiver">
    <intent-filter  >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.mypackage.com" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Broadcast Receiver:**

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
private WebView mWebview ;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context con, Intent intent)
 {

    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    mWebview.clearCache(true);
}
}
```

But, I cannot access the webview in the broadcast receiver. Any idea on how to get this done exactly? Maybe I'm getting something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `context` you are using to find your `WebView` reference by `findViewById` is the `context` from the `Receiver` and not a `context` from an `Activity` therefor it can't access the `WebView`

There are a lot of possibilities:

#### Solution 1

You can use `LocalBroadcastReceiver` to communicate with the activity that holds the reference to your `WebView`, from there you can properly clear the cache like you were trying to do in the receiver. `mWebview.clearCache(true);`

#### Solution 2

In the `onReceive` of your BroadcastReceiver you can store a preference in the `SharedPreferences` telling that an updated has occurred.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context con, Intent intent)
 {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("hasAppUpdated", true).apply();
}
```

And then in your `Activity` that deals with the `WebView` you can verify if there was an App update and clear the cache of the `WebView`.

To access the value from the `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
Boolean hasAppUpdated = prefs.getBoolean("hasAppUpdated", false);


if(hasAppUpdated) {
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("hasAppUpdated", false).apply();
    mWebview.clearCache(true);
}
```

The `false` value is the default value for the `hasAppUpdated`, and after getting the value from the preferences you might want to make the preference back to false again.

#### Ugly solution

Another way of doing that might be this ugly hack that **I don't recommend**.
I didn't test this but if you are using `WebView` then the cache folder of your app probably contain a folder `org.chromium.android_webview` (for versions bellow API 19 this might not be true since the `WebView` back then didn't use chromium) and inside that folder you have the cache of your `WebView` so if you remove the files inside this folder using the `java.io.File` API you probably have your problem solved without requiring accessing the `WebView`. Remember that this is a super ugly solution(if it even works) and is far from being a bullet-proof solution.

[image]